# Which document describe the result class of every api call in microsoft graph php sdk?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, officedev

```
$user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me")
                      ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                      ->execute();
```

How can I know the return type of /me call is Model\User::class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine endpoint *entity type* the following approach could be considered. Set `Accept` header to `odata.metadata=full` to return `@odata.type` property along with data in response payload(refer [OData spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-os.html#_Toc372793042) for a more details)

**Example**

```
$resp = $client->createRequest("GET", "/me")
    ->addHeaders(array(
        "Accept" => "application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true"
    ))
    ->execute();

$entity = $resp->getBody();
$entityType = $entity["@odata.type"];
```

**Result**

For the provide example `$entityType` returns  `#microsoft.graph.user` which corresponds to `Microsoft\Graph\Model\User` type from `msgraph-sdk-php`